Memory leak anxiety for SDL_ttf functions
I'm using SDL2 and SDL2_ttf libs in the code below. It runs OK for now but I'm anxious for leaking memory. Do I need to uncomment the commented lines and free the surface & texture pointers each time the loop calls the function? Do TTF_RenderText_Blended & SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface functions allocate new memory space each time the loop calls the textRender function?
...
...
...
typedef struct tSomeStruct {
    SDL_Window *sdlWind;
    SDL_Renderer *sdlRend;
    SDL_Surface *sdlSurf;
    SDL_Texture *sdlText;
    ...
    ...
    ...
} tSomeStruct;

tSomeStruct vars;

void textRender(
    char *someText,
    char *otherText
) {
    vars.sdlSurf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(vars.font, someText, (SDL_Color) { 0, 127, 191, 255 });
    vars.sdlText = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(vars.sdlRend, vars.sdlSurf);
    SDL_RenderCopy(vars.sdlRend, vars.sdlText, NULL, &(SDL_Rect){1125, 100, 150, 32});
    // SDL_FreeSurface(vars.sdlSurf);
    // SDL_DestroyTexture(vars.sdlText);

    vars.sdlSurf = TTF_RenderText_Blended(vars.font, otherText, (SDL_Color) { 0, 127, 191, 255 });
    vars.sdlText = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(vars.sdlRend, vars.sdlSurf);
    SDL_RenderCopy(vars.sdlRend, vars.sdlText, NULL, &(SDL_Rect){1125, 300, 150, 32});
    // SDL_FreeSurface(vars.sdlSurf);
    // SDL_DestroyTexture(vars.sdlText);

    return;
}
...
...
...
int main(
    int argc,
    char *argv[]
) {
    if (sdlInit() == SUCCESS) {
        varsInit();

        while (running) {
            eventEvaluate();
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff);
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
            textRender();
            ...
            ...
            ...
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
            SDL_Delay(timeDelay);
        }

        sdlQuit();
    }

    return(0);
}


Yes, you're leaking textures and surfaces.

The TTF_RenderText_Blended documentation seems pretty clear: "This function will allocate a new..." so you should call SDL_FreeSurface on the returned pointer when you're done with the surface. Likewise for SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface , call SDL_DestroyTexture when done

@HolyBlackCat & @TedLyngmo; thanks for your quick & valuable comments.

In the future, if you're concerned about leaking memory, learn to use analysis tools like valgrind
